# Plotting two sets of circle data on one figure

Tags: python, plot, graph, figure, circle-pack

I want to produce a code that puts the two graphs on top of one another however instead i get two seperate graphs:
My code is as follows:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(len(list_of_disks)):
    circle1 = plt.Circle((list_of_disks[i].x, list_of_disks[i].y), radius)
    plt.xlim(0,1)
    plt.ylim(0,1)
    plt.grid(linestyle='--')
    ax.add_artist(circle1)
plt.show()

if len(percolated_cluster) != 0:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for i in range(len(percolated_cluster[0])):
        circle1 = plt.Circle((percolated_cluster[0][i].x, percolated_cluster[0][i].y), radius, color = 'red')
        plt.xlim(0,1)
        plt.ylim(0,1)
        plt.grid(linestyle='--')
        ax.add_artist(circle1)
    plt.show()
```

But when i run the program i receive two figures rather than one figure with both sets of data plotted on it.
How would I ensure that both sets of data are plotted on one graph.
For reference i obtain the following in two seperate screens:

[image]

But woudl like both sets of data to be plotted together.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the number of columns in your subplot figure:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(len(list_of_disks)):
    circle1 = plt.Circle((list_of_disks[i].x, list_of_disks[i].y), radius)
    ax.xlim(0,1)
    ax.ylim(0,1)
    ax.grid(linestyle='--')
    ax.add_artist(circle1)

if len(percolated_cluster) != 0:
    for i in range(len(percolated_cluster[0])):
        circle1 = plt.Circle((percolated_cluster[0][i].x, percolated_cluster[0][i].y), radius, color = 'red')
        ax.grid(linestyle='--')
        ax.add_artist(circle1)
plt.show()
```

A useful reference: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html

Comment: Hi, this still produces two images, I would like there to be one plot with red and blue discs where the red discs show the cluster that touches both sides and blue for the clusters that do not.